# Automatizar script de Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle-11g

Quisiera saber si es posible automatizar un script en el manejador de base de datos de Oracle.

Lo que pasa es que tengo que ejecutar 3 líneas o queries, todos los días. Y quisiera saber si existe una manera de hacer automatizado.

Los queries son 3 select, o sea, solamente consulto unos datos para ver el status.

Comment: ¿Y que quieres que suceda con los resultados de los 3 select? ¿Quién los vería y cómo, siendo que se trata de algo automatizado?

Comment: Lo que quiero con los 3 select, es que se ejecuten y me muestre los resultados. Solamente seria para mi. Entonces podria ser de la manera mas simple.

Comment: tendria que volver cada query un plsql y cada plsql en un job que se ejecute en las horas que usted mencione y que le envie un correo pero necesita un servidor de correos http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL
o puede instalar el oracle report
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24269_01/doc.11120/e23960/overview.htm#FRINS162
y hacer consultar del los reportes mediante una pagina web local cuando lo desee

Comment: sobre que sistema operativo corre tu base de datos? y si podrias postear el resultado de tu query cuantas columnas tiene?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre:

1. crear un `store procedure` con la lógica de tus `select`
2. crear un `job` que ejecute el store procedure
3. con respecto a la consulta de datos puedes hacerlo de diferentes maneras: programar tareas, envió de correos, mediante tu aplicación mostrar un `select` etc.

Comment: esto es mas un comentario extendido, considera que al responder no es solo decir que hacer sino además el como